# Настройка VPS без панели новичку

Tags: linux, администрирование, веб-сервер

Сайты вырастают из шаред хостинга, планирую переезд на VPS. Неделю читал в сети что да как про VPS. 
Вижу два пути настройки VPS: Первый, ставлю панель Ispmanager 5 lite и там администрирую сервер, но там тоже, судя по их форуму проблем хватает, например php7 работает только в cgi режиме. 
Второй вариант - все поставить самому с нуля - nginx+apache+mysql+php и прочее. Но возможно ли это правильно поставить и что бы работало стабильно новичку? Почитал мануалы - с одной стороны вроде понятно, но с другой очень много нюансов. Есть ли полные манулы с комментариями по настройке веб сервера?
Опытные администраторы, посоветуйте с чего начинать, обойтись панелью управления с ее ограничениями или лезть в linux?

Comment: Начать с установки линукса на свой домашний компьютер ;) А там появится какой-нибудь базовый опыт дальше и всё понятно станет

Comment: Проблемы вознигающие с десктопным `GNU/Linux` сильно отличаются от проблем серверного. Смена десктопной ОСи полезна разве-что как дополнительный стимул к изучению `GNU/Linux` в целом. Ну и из линукса проще работать с линуксом. Для начала просто попробуй настроить сервер вручную, даже если не получится то это будет опыт

Answer (score 2):

Лично я считаю что панели для новичка это зло и новичку нужно как раз все поставить самому чтоб понять как оно работает.
Вышеуказанное ПО легко поставить и настроить новичку, а тем более учитывая громадное количество материалов в интернете, проблемы у новичка могут возникнуть разве что с настройкой проксирования через `nginx`, поэтому я б на вашем месте просто отказался от `apache` в пользу `nginx` либо наоборот.

Comment: А бывают ли готовые образы ОС настроенные под вебсервер, т.е. уже все установлено debian+php7+nginx+apache+mysql и т.п.?

Comment: Я не смотрел так что не знаю, наверно есть но это можно сделать во всех популярных дистрибутивах одной командой

Comment: В целом согласен что панели зло, но нужно понимать что ручная настройка для новичка это известный вызов. Нужно быть готовым разбираться с тем как оно работает и почему что-то не работает.

Comment: Отказ от `apache` не самое беспроблемное решение, пропадёт поддержка `.htaccess` файлов и соответственно что-то реализованное ими может отвалиться (а сайты с шаред-хостнгов любят использовать `.htaccess` на каждый чих). Нужно быть готовым переносить настройки из `.htaccess` в конфиги nginx, php-fpm или логику приложения (вручную и вдумчево). Если сайтов много то это может быть проблемой.